# JWT: How much I can trust to my payloads

Tags: security, authentication, jwt

suppose I create a jwt token for a user and set a payload as:

`['userID'=>1, 'role'=>'user']`
In case of using HTTPS and SSL, Is it safe to send role or any other sensitive information via payload? Is it possible for sender to manipulate payload values?

**UPDATE**: Now I know that JWT tokens are decodable. But because they carrying a signature, any update on the values shall invalidate the token. If you want the payload be totally encrypted, try **JWE**!

Answer (score 3):

Claims in the payload can not be manipulated with out the key, a common example is admin=false, both the client and server can see that this user is not an admin. If the user was to try and manipulate the token (to become an admin) it would not validate correctly. This is why its critically important you validate your tokens before reading any claims from them.

However you wouldn’t normally put sensitive information (like credit card numbers) in them because the claims are not encrypted however no one should be able to access your token otherwise they would be able to take over your session.

Have a play with manipulating tokens here https://jwt.io/

Comment: So is all the claims visible to consumer as plain text? I mean if a token is encoded in an ugly1.ugly2.ugly3 string and secret is not revealed to consumer, how it's possible to decrypt payload?

Comment: Have a look at the stack overflow documentation [Introduction to JSON Web Tokens](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jwt/5213/introduction-to-json-web-tokens/18559/signed-jwt-jws#t=201608220422564473964). They are base64 encoded, you  don't need a key to decode. (Google: base64 decode)

Answer (score 2):

JWT tokens are digitally signed by the issuer, so they cannot be modified without invalidating the signature.

HTTPS is only required to prevent the token from being stolen.